# Vba -display text of combobox to left center

Tags: vba, combobox, text-alignment

I have combobox in sheet which display text in proper alignment when the size of combobox is small , as in following pic :

[image: Text in small combobox]

but text in bigger combobox is as following :

[image: text in bigger combobox]

their are left ,center and right text-align properties for combobox .

is their any way to make the text align to "left-center" ??

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Form` ComboBox instead of an `ActiveX` one, and the selected value will appear vertically centered whatever the combobox hieght

You find the `Form` ComboBox in the upmost controls menu when clicking Developer-> Insert Controls

Comment: @speedyraz, did you get through it?